# Zero key on keypad works on and off

Tags: keyboard

I'm using an XPSP3 host, and for a while now, I noticed that the 0 key on the keypad sometimes stops working for a few hours and starts working again, without rebooting in between.

It could be a minor virus, but scans by either Comodo or Kaspersky returned nothing.

Has someone seen this? What else could I do to investigate?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the keyboard with another computer.

Comment: It's almost certainly the keyboard itself -- this sort of failure is not at all unusual.  If you use the numeric pad a lot it may simply be worn out, or something that you spilled into the KB years ago may be coming back to haunt you.  Try picking up the KB and "gently" rapping the edge of it on your desk, from several different angles.  This occasionally dislodge crud that's causing trouble.  Otherwise get a new KB.  Unless the current one has some emotional attachment they're hardly ever worth trying to repair (though I've done it several times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the keyboard on another computer, or pop a linux distro in the drive and test out the key in a live OS to see if the problem occurs still, if it does, it's the keyboard.

If it doesn't try updating or rolling back drivers.